# Erro ao executar o JAR no docker-compose

Tags: docker

Observem o erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele informa que meu arquivo JAR deu erro e por causa disso não foi executado;

O meu arquivo docker-compose.yml deve está com erro, e por falta de experiência não estou conseguindo identificar, preciso de ajuda, esse é meu arquivo;

```
version: '3'
services: 
  kwan:
      image: postgres:11.5
      network_mode: bridge
      container_name: postgres

      expose:
      - 5432
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      environment:
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_DB=root
      restart: unless-stopped
  springapi:
      image: openjdk:10-jre-slim
      container_name: springapi
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - kwan
      command: ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

É importante informa que meu sistema operacional é o Windows 10!

Essa é minha pasta!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei dessa forma;

```
version: '3'
services: 
  kwan:
      image: postgres:11.5
      network_mode: bridge
      container_name: postgres

      expose:
      - 5432
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      environment:
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_DB=root
      restart: unless-stopped
  springapi:
      image: openjdk:10-jre-slim
      container_name: springapi
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - kwan
      volumes:
      - dockerTest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/application.jar
      command: ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=docker-demo", "application.jar"]
```

Porém ele gera esse erro;

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: Named volume "dockerTest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/application.jar:rw" is used in service "springapi" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

Eu também tantei dessa forma;

```
version: '3'
services: 
  kwan:
      image: postgres:11.5
      network_mode: bridge
      container_name: postgres

      expose:
      - 5432
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      environment:
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_DB=root
      restart: unless-stopped
  jar:
      image: openjdk:8-jre-slim
      volumes:
          - ./dockerTest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      command: "bash" -c "java -Dspring.profiles.active=docker-demo"
```

Porém gerou esse erro;

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 18, column 7
expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 21, column 23
```

Comment: E o seu arquivo se chama `dockerTest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, de onde saiu esse `application.jar`?

Comment: eu era para criar um apelido para o jar, eu ainda estou aprendendo a mexer do docker.

Comment: Tente colocar no `volumes` algo como `"./dockerTest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/application.jar"` e no comando também colocar `/application.jar`

Comment: gerou erro:

springapi    | Error: Could not find or load main class .application.jar
springapi    | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /application/jar
springapi exited with code 1

Answer (score 0):

Tenta mudar o "command" no servico jar para:

```
command: ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=docker-demo", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```